# Render Account/Login.cshtml view on another page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to be able to offer our users 2 ways to login, via 2 different pages in our MVC 6 application.

Currently i have my Account/Login.cshtml view with the AccountController (standard template generated).

On my view Home/Welcome.cshtml, is there anyway i can include the login view and still have the AccountController dealing with all the login stuff.

I do not want to have to duplicate anything.

Sorry very new to MVC

Answer (score 0):

Redirect the user to Account/Login controller from Home/Welcome controller.  Before redirecting please check if user is logged in/Authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [Partial View](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/dd410123(v=vs.100).aspx).
Partial view is special view which renders a portion of view content. It is just like a user control web form application. Partial can be reusable in multiple views. It helps us to reduce code duplication. In other word a partial view enables us to render a view within the parent view.[Read more](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/partial-view-in-mvc/)

What you can do is to make you login page as partial page and then render this on 2 different Views.

Comment: Can a partial View have its own controller?  I changed converting my Account/Login.cshtml to a partialView but get errors with Model etc

Comment: No it's not necessary to create controller for partial view, You have to pass Model when you are rendering partial view. Check these http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/898017/Different-Ways-to-Pass-Data-to-Partial-View  http://pratapreddypilaka.blogspot.in/2011/11/partial-views-with-diefferent-models.html